# Azcopy copy within the same container to different directory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I am trying to copy some files from one folder to another within the same storage account and container but getting the below error:

Command:

```
azcopy copy "https://store_name.dfs.core.windows.net/xyz/sample.db/folder_name/folder_id=10/*" "https://store_name.dfs.core.windows.net/xyz/sample_copy.db/folder_name/folder_id=10/" --recursive
```

Error:

```
INFO: The parameters you supplied were Source: 'https://store_name.dfs.core.windows.net/xyz/sample.db/folder_name/folder_id=10/*' of type BlobFS, and Destination: 'https://store_name.dfs.core.windows.net/xyz/sample_copy.db/folder_name/folder_id=10/' of type BlobFS
INFO: Based on the parameters supplied, a valid source-destination combination could not automatically be found. Please check the parameters you supplied.
```

Notice that only the folder name after the container xyz is different. Both source and destination folders exist.

I have tried adding the parameter --from-to BlobFSBlobFS but it still doesn't work.
I can see that it allows to copy from Azure Blob -> Azure Blob in the azcopy documentation but not sure why this doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

In my environment, I'm using **`Azcopy version 10.13.0`** to copy files from one folder to another folder within the same storage account(Standard account).

In my storage account ,**`first folder structure`**:

```
test/sample.db/folder_name/folder_id=10  #with some files
```

[image]

**`Second folder structure:`**

```
 test/sample_copy.db/folder_name/folder_id=10   #with one file
```

[image]

**Command:**

```
azcopy copy "https://venkat123.dfs.core.windows.net/test/sample.db/folder_name/folder_id=10/*?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-08-12T12:51:58Z&st=2023-08-12T04:51:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxx" "https://venkat123.dfs.core.windows.net/test/sample_copy.db/folder_name/folder_id=10/?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-08-12T12:51:58Z&st=2023-08-12T04:51:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxx" --recursive=true
```

The above command **`storage endpoint + sas token`** copied successfully from one folder to another folder.

**Output:**

```
INFO: Switching to use blob endpoint on source account.
INFO: Switching to use blob endpoint on destination account.
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: azcopy: A newer version 10.20.0 is available to download

INFO: Any empty folders will be processed, because source and destination both support folders

Job xxxxxx has started
Log file is located at: /home/venkatesan/.azcopy/xxxxx.log

100.0 %, 3 Done, 0 Failed, 2 Pending, 0 Skipped, 5 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 0.0497


Job xxxxxxx summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0667
Number of File Transfers: 5
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 5
Number of Transfers Completed: 5
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 12429
Final Job Status: Completed
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Copy blobs between Azure storage accounts with AzCopy v10 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json)